# Ubuntu PHP APACHE2 fresh install issue

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

i compiled myself apache2 and php5.2 using this guide http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html

i tested php with phpinfo(); and all seems ok

after i successfully installed drupal6, after i login if i try to go to Administer link on the menu ( localhost/?q=admin ) the browser takes me to ( localhost/?q=admin ) but on the screen i see

```
Index of /

    * CHANGELOG.txt
    * cron.php
    * includes/
    * index.php
    * install.php
    * misc/
    * modules/
    * profiles/
    * xmlrpc.php
```

** some files/folders were omitted for shortening of this question

what can cause this ?

Comment: i compiled apache with --enable-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to localhost/index.php?q=admin - does it work? If so, are you sure you followed the

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

part of the Apache configuration?